# Set an img's top-margin dependant to another div's height

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin

So I have this question/answer looking html and there's an img on each side of two speechbubbles. I would like for the second img to be aligned with the second speechbubble and therefore for its top-margin to increase or decrease according to the height inside the first speechbubble.
Here's my code:

```css
.question{
width:100%;
height:auto;
line-height:20px;
color:{color:Answer};
}

.questionin {    
    position: relative;
    width: 415px;
    min-height: 25px;  
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left:55px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    background: #D8D8D8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}

.questionin:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #D8D8D8;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -15px;
    top: 7px;
}

.askavatar {
  width:30px;
  padding:3px;
  margin-right:4px;
  -webkit-transition:.3s ease;
  -moz-transition:.3s ease;
  -o-transition:.3s ease;
  transition:.3s ease;
}

.askavatar:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

#questionavatar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -55px;
}

#answeravatar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -55px;
}

.answer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    width: 425px;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #97c5e0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}

.answer::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 15px;
    border-color: transparent #97c5e0;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    right: -14px;
    top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
<img src="{AskerPortraitURL-48}"
align="left"id="questionavatar" class="askavatar"><img src="{image:Avatar}" align="right" id="answeravatar" class="askavatar"></div>
<div class="questionin">
This is a question : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
<div class="answer">
This is an answer : Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</div>
```

It's normal that the second img is a bit off to the right becayse my original width is 435 and the snippet is not. I tried with percentages but It didn't work with a longer text. Do you know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current html structure, it's almost impossible to achieve what you are looking for. I have slightly changed your html and css, see code snippet

```css
.questionin {    
    position: relative;
    width: 415px;
    min-height: 25px;  
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left:55px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    background: #D8D8D8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}

.questionin:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #D8D8D8;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -15px;
    top: 7px;
}

.avatar {
  width:30px;
  padding:3px;
  margin-right:4px;
  -webkit-transition:.3s ease;
  -moz-transition:.3s ease;
  -o-transition:.3s ease;
  transition:.3s ease;
}

.avatar:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

#questionavatar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -55px;
}

#answeravatar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -55px;
}

.answer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    width: 425px;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #97c5e0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}

.answer::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 15px;
    border-color: transparent #97c5e0;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    right: -14px;
    top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!--
  YOU DO NOT NEED THIS TAG
<div class="question">
</div>
-->
<div class="questionin">
<img src="{AskerPortraitURL-48}"
align="left"id="questionavatar" class="askavatar">
This is a question : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
<div class="answer">
<img src="{image:Avatar}" align="right" id="answeravatar" class="askavatar">
This is an answer : Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</div>
```

Updated: Your avatars are visible now

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! What you did seemed like a good way to make it work but I don't know why now the imgs are gone and I did exactly as you said (I just changed avatar class to askavatar because I already had this class in another part of my code.. Can I tell you something for you to be able to help me ?

Comment: Please update your changes so I can inspect where is problem

Comment: Your html structure is wrong. You need to put`<img src="{AskerPortraitURL-48}"
align="left"id="questionavatar" class="askavatar">` inside `<div class="questionin">` and `<img src="{image:Avatar}" align="right" id="answeravatar" class="askavatar">` inside `<div class="answer">`. I have made an edit request so you can test it

Answer (score 0):

For now, the easiest solution is to give the image a `position: absolute`; as the answer speech bubble is `position: relative;`. To give it the right position, you have to add `right: 0;`.

You can see the result in the snippet below:

```css
.question{
width:100%;
height:auto;
line-height:20px;
color:{color:Answer};
}

.questionin {
    margin-left:55px;
    {block:if250pxPosts}
    width:185px;
    {/block:if250pxPosts}
    {block:PermalinkPage}
    width:425px;
    {/block:PermalinkPage}
position: relative;
width: 415px;
min-height: 25px;
padding: 5px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
background: #D8D8D8;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}

.questionin:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
border-color: transparent #D8D8D8;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -15px;
top: 7px;
}
 
.question img{
width:30px;
padding:3px;
margin-right:4px;
-webkit-transition:.3s ease;
-moz-transition:.3s ease;
-o-transition:.3s ease;
transition:.3s ease;
}

.question img:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
-moz-transform: scale(1.5);
-ms-transform: scale(1.5);
transform: scale(1.5);
}

#answeravatar{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.answer {
    {block:if250pxPosts}
    width:185px;
    {/block:if250pxPosts}
    {block:PermalinkPage}
    width:425px;
    {/block:PermalinkPage}
position: relative;
margin-top:10px;
width: 425px;
min-height: 30px;
padding: 5px;
background: #97c5e0;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
-moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}

.answer:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px 0 10px 15px;
border-color: transparent #97c5e0;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
right: -14px;
top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
<img src="{AskerPortraitURL-48}"
align="left" id="questionavatar">
<div class="questionin">
This is a question : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
<div class="answer">
<img src="{image:Avatar}" align="right"id="answeravatar">
This is an answer : Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know why but this didn't work. It made the answer avatar go all the way to the right and at the same height of the first question speechbubble.